# Webdriverio selenium standalone doesn't update driver version

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I made little demo projects with WebdriverIO 6, Typescript and cucumber.
I have put this in the configuration file wdio.CHROME.conf.ts:

```
import { config } from './wdio.conf';
import { CHROME_ARGS } from './chrome-args';

const seleniumConfig = {
  version: '3.141.59',
  drivers: { chrome: { version: '87.0.4280.20' } },
};

const browserOptions: WebDriver.ChromeOptions & { args: Array<string> } = {
args: [
...CHROME_ARGS,
...(process.argv.includes('--headless') ? ['--headless', '--no-sandbox'] : []),
'--window-size=1920,1080',
 ],
};

const seleniumOpts = config.services?.find(
  (service) => Array.isArray(service) && service[0] === 'selenium-standalone'
) as SeleniumStandaloneOptions;

seleniumOpts.args = { ...seleniumConfig };
seleniumOpts.installArgs = { ...seleniumConfig };

console.log(seleniumOpts);

const browserConfig: WebdriverIO.Config = {
...config,
capabilities: [
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  'goog:chromeOptions': browserOptions,
  },
 ],
};

exports.config = browserConfig;
```

And this in wdio.conf.ts:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path';
import { commandsFactory } from './commands-factory';

export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
  
  specs: [
    './src/features/**/*.feature',
    // './src/features/login.feature',
    // './src/features/dashboard.feature'
  ],
  
  exclude: [
    
  ],
 
  maxInstances: 1,
  logLevel: 'trace',
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'http://automationpractice.com',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: [
    [
      'selenium-standalone',
      {
        logs: 'logs',
      },
    ],
  ],
  outputDir: path.join(appRoot.path, '/logs'),

  framework: 'cucumber',
  reporters: [
    'spec',
    [
      'allure',
      {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
        useCucumberStepReporter: true,
      },
    ],
  ],

  cucumberOpts: {
    backtrace: false,
    failAmbiguousDefinitions: true,
    failFast: false,
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
    name: [],
    snippets: false,
    source: true,
    profile: [],
    require: [
      './src/step_definitions/*.ts',
    ],
    snippetSyntax: undefined,
    strict: true,
    tagExpression: 'not @Login',
    tagsInTitle: false,
    timeout: 60000,
  },



  before(capabilities, specs) {
    const commands = commandsFactory({ waitForTimeout: this.waitforTimeout });

    /* eslint-disable */
    const chai = require('chai');
    global.should = chai.should();

    // Sample command
    function browserCustomCommandExample(text) {
      console.log(text);
    }

    browser.addCommand('browserCustomCommandExample', browserCustomCommandExample);

    Object.keys(commands).forEach((key) => {
      browser.addCommand(key, commands[key]);
    });
  },

  afterStep(step, context, { error, result, passed, duration }) {
    if (error) {
      browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
  },
};
```

But after I do `npm install` and try to run tests `npm run test:chrome:headless`, I get this error:

```
[0-0]  Error:  Failed to create session.
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-QUTK6LBV', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_271'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I have tried to update version of the driver in wdio.CHROME.conf.ts to 87, but it didn't help.
It just doesn't download version 87 of chrome driver, instead it is stuck with version 85.
When I look at the `node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\chromedriver` there is only version 85 and it wouldn't download the version 87 (85 was previous version I had in configuration file).
On my machine, chrome browser version is 87 and it needs the same version of chrome driver in order to work (from my understanding :D )
I tried deleting `node_modules` and doing it from scratch but with no success.
This is link to my repo https://github.com/mareru/webdriverIO-shop-demo
Can someone please help :)
Thanks!

Comment: I see you are trying to use my example from https://gitlab.com/bar_foo/wdio-cucumber-typescript/-/blob/master/config/wdio.CHROME.conf.ts

Comment: Not sure what went wrong, maybe some typo when copy pasting, make sure to use latest versions of @wdio, delete package lock json and node modules, reinstall packages and try again

Comment: @MikeG. I fixed it slightly different form from your example. Would you have done it differently? It works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced these lines:

```
const seleniumOpts = config.services?.find(
  (service) => Array.isArray(service) && service[0] === 'selenium-standalone'
) as SeleniumStandaloneOptions;

seleniumOpts.args = { ...seleniumConfig };
seleniumOpts.installArgs = { ...seleniumConfig };
```

With these ones

```
config.services = [
  [
    'selenium-standalone',
    {
      logs: 'logs',
      args: seleniumConfig,
      installArgs: seleniumConfig,
    },
  ],
];
```

And it worked. It seems like previous code didn't generate the curly braces well.
Parameters logs, args, installArgs should have been in joint curly brace not in separate curly braces.
It generated this:

```
  [
    'selenium-standalone',
    { logs: 'logs' },
                         args: { version: '3.141.59', drivers: [Object] },
    installArgs: { version: '3.141.59', drivers: [Object] }
  ]
]
```

While it should have been like this

```
[
  [
    'selenium-standalone',
    { logs: 'logs', args: [Object], installArgs: [Object] }
  ]
]
```